# i have a problem on command cooldown discord.py

Tags: discord.py

Hi I have a problem in my command cooldown here's the code

```py
from discord.ext.commands.cooldowns import BucketType, Cooldown

def cooldown(rate, per_sec=0, per_min=0, per_hour=0, per_day=0, type=commands.BucketType.default):
    return commands.cooldown(rate, per_sec + 60 * per_min + 3600 * per_hour + 86400 * per_day, type)
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 86400, BucketType.user)
```

and the bot doesn't respond to my command since i added the cooldown thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import BucketType

Use build-in **discord.py** cooldowns like this:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 60, BucketType.user)
async def command(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Command called.")
```

You also can process error when command is on cooldown:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, exception):
    if isinstance(exception, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.send(f"You are rate limitted. Please, try again in {exception.retry_after} seconds")
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply it worked but for the event It didnt can you help me with ?

Comment: Hello! I edited my answer. Check it out again, please.

Comment: thanks it worked but if i want to make it not by seconds by hours how may I ?

Comment: Write `@commands.cooldown(1, 3600, BucketType.user)`. Unfortunately, you can only use seconds. For example 3 hours is `3600 * 3` seconds.

Comment: okay thank you !

I have another question i used a command that they have to mention but if they doesn't mention the command is talking about them like this:
`if member ==None:`
   `member = ctx.author`
and now when i use it without mention the bot stills tell me to mention someone

Comment: @SIDAL, Write something like this: `async def command(ctx, member: Optional[discord.Member])`. (You need to use `from typing import Optional` before it).

Comment: okay thx for all your help !